# Remove elements in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

can some one show how to work with few elements in DOM and move them from one block to another, I need use jQuery, for example I have this structure

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="block_left">
        <div class="title">title 1</div>
        <div class="image">image 1 for title 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block_right">

    </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <div class="block_left">
        <div class="title">title 2</div>
        <div class="image">image 2 for title 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block_right">

    </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <div class="block_left">
        <div class="title">title 3</div>
        <div class="image">image 3 for title 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block_right">

    </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <div class="block_left">
        <div class="title">title 4</div>
        <div class="image">image 4 for title 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block_right">

    </div>
</div>
```

I was trying to use jQuery `.each()` but not that I need. In result I need this:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="block_left">
        <div class="title">title 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block_right">
        <div class="image">image 1 for title 1</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <div class="block_left">
        <div class="title">title 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block_right">
        <div class="image">image 2 for title 2</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <div class="block_left">
        <div class="title">title 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block_right">
        <div class="image">image 3 for title 3</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <div class="block_left">
        <div class="title">title 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block_right">
        <div class="image">image 4 for title 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I remove elements? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".image").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".block_right").append($(this));
});
```

Try that code, should work!

Goodluck.

Answer (score 2):

To append the `.image` elements to the next `.block_right` elements you can do

```
$('.block_right').append(function() {
    return $(this).prev().find('.image');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/V7Ye6/)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution with `.each()`:

```
$('.block .image').each(function() {
    $(this).closest('.block').find('.block_right').append(this);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/6afBy/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)** here:

```
$('.block_left .image').each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo($(this).parent().next()); 
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8wkH8/)**

Comment: you missed the context of `this`